# Rails 4 - Adding an image tag to a wrap bootstrap template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, path

I'm struggling big time.

Im trying to figure out how to replace an img_src tag from wrap bootstrap with an image tag or image url for rails show. I've tried at least 20 different variations on the below. Nothing is working. The page renders, but the image doesn't show.

can anyone see how to put an image tag into this line?

```
data-background="<%= image_tag("testimonial.jpg",  :style=>"background-repeat: repeat !important; background-size: inherit !important;")%>"
```

Comment: Don't use image_tag in this case, but image_path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

```
data-background="<%= image_path 'testimonial.jpg' %>"
```

and set your style separately. In this case image_tag would generate a complete `<img>` tag at this point of your code and this would not render.